# How to automatically download matching entries from Socorro and Bugzilla servers?

Tags: mysql, database, import, mozilla, bugzilla

This is part one of a complex question.

The goal is to download all crash reports that have a bug id assigned to them (or just all of them) from the `Socorro server`. This needs to be done for several versions of the FennecAndroid product.

> https://crash-stats.mozilla.org/topcrashers/?product=FennecAndroid&version=49.0a1&days=7
>   (there might be a better way to access the actual data instead of statistics I haven't found yet)

But there is also a second part to this problem as for each downloaded crash report I have to download and store the corresponding `Bugzilla` bug entries indicated by bug id`s.

And lastly I need to find a tool or method to import downloaded entries from both Socorro and `Bugzilla` into a local `MySQL database` (into different tables of course).

Needless to say right now I don't know how to solve any of these problems, so any assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated!